# Is there any way of simulating the effect of the c++11 'override' specifier in c++03?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

In c++11 adding the 'override' specifier to a virtual method in a derived class declares the intent to override a virtual function in the base class.

Is there a way of achieving a similar effect in C++03, assuming that it's only possible to modify the derived class and not the base class?

Comment: You could, for example, write a class that directly inherits from the base class and which uses a different technique to provide the implementation based on your original derived class (CRTP, only pure virtuals, ..).

Comment: @dyp: good idea. unfortunately my motivation for this is that I've got  a huge poorly documented legacy codebase, so in this specific case it wouldn't be practical. Definitely something to bear in mid for future use cases though.

Comment: And compiling your code with a C++11 compiler is not an option?

Comment: Well you could apply this "pattern" partially, by wrapping only those member functions for which you want to emulate `override`.

Comment: @filmor: Yes and no. I can optionally compile the code with a c++11 complier but I don't have a c++11 cross compiler for the target platform. So I suppose I could have a macro which resolved to "override" if c++11, and to nothing if c++03. This seems time consuming and messy, but may be the best available option.

Answer (score 5):

No.

One trick I have used when I could modify the base class was to make the base class method pure virtual.  Even if it had a default implementation: you can have both.

Now children who fail to override generate an error if instantiated.  If you want the default implementation, call the base class version from the child.